# Can Overflow menu on Android be used for "sorting menu" instead of usual help n settings in its options?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, overflow

I am designing an app for android and i need to know if it is good idea to used "overflow menu" as a provision to display "sorting menu" as for example "by date, by name" instead of just using that area for displaying help and settings?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As a user, I think that's and odd choice. Depends of what kind of other options there are, but if there aren't any other, I'd suggest you put these in the action bar. The menu is for me the place to hold the other, less frequently used options.

So basically that's up to you and what you intend to put as options. If there are more important ones, it's clear you should put them first, and disregard the sorting options in the "overflow menu".

Comment: Hi Carp, Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking of using navigation drawer option for all my top links which are just 5 including "settings". Let me know what you think now, if i can keep overflow menu for sorting options now as I don't have any other menu options apart from top links which will come under navigation drawer.

Comment: Yeah, sure, I think that's fine! Just reconsider prioritizing if you change your mind though